# how to inject a dependent service into controller in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

In my project, there three modules, Role depends on User, User depends on Tenant, Tenant depends on Role. To avoiding circular dependencies, I create a service that encapsulates the functionalities that would otherwise cause the circular dependency issue. I have spend all a day yet still not make it work.

remove-role.service

```
...
@Injectable()
export class RemoveRoleService {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private roleService: RoleService,
  ) { }

  async remove(id: number) {
    const users = await this.userService.getUsers(id, 'role_id');
    if (users.length > 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException({ errorCode: 1035 })
    }
    const user = await this.roleService.remove(id);
    return user
  }
  ...
}
```

now i import it in role.controller.

````
export class RoleController {
  constructor(
    private readonly roleService: RoleService,
    private readonly removeRoleService: RemoveRoleService,
  ) { }
  ...
}
```

when saved. the compiler throws the error:
```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RoleController (RoleService, ?). Please make sure that the argument RemoveRoleService at index [1] is available in the RoleModule context.
Potential solutions:
- Is RoleModule a valid NestJS module?
- If RemoveRoleService is a provider, is it part of the current RoleModule?
- If RemoveRoleService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RoleModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing RemoveRoleService */ ]
  })
```

so how to import this servie, may i do something in role.module?
```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RoleService } from './role.service';
import { RoleController } from './role.controller';
import { UseMongoose } from 'src/utils/use-mongoose';
import { Role, RoleSchema } from './schemas/role.schema';
import { RoleMenuModule } from '../roleMenu/roleMenu.module';
import { RemoveRoleService } from './remove-role.service';

@Module({
  imports: [UseMongoose(Role.name, RoleSchema, true), RoleMenuModule],
  controllers: [RoleController],
  providers: [RoleService],
  exports: [RoleService]
})
export class RoleModule { }

```
````

Comment: In what module do you create the `RemoveRoleService`?

Comment: hi, Jay McDoniel, it's just a dependent service, no module using it. If using a module and import this service, it will cause circular dependency issue.

Comment: If no module registers this provider, how is Nest supposed to know about it?